Sequelize in Docker Container Fails to Connect to PostgreSQL Database - ECONNREFUSED Error
I’m facing an issue where my user-service Docker container fails to connect to my PostgreSQL database container using Sequelize. I keep getting the ECONNREFUSED error, and I’ve tried multiple steps to resolve it, but none have worked so far.
Environment:

Docker Version: 20.10.17
Sequelize CLI Version: 6.6.2
PostgreSQL Image: postgres:14
Node Version: 18-alpine

Error:
When running npx sequelize-cli db:migrate, I encounter the following error:
ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db

In the container logs:
SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.2:5432

Project Structure:

Dockerized Environment: Both the user-service and PostgreSQL database are Dockerized using docker-compose.
Sequelize Configuration: Using environment variables to configure Sequelize and connecting via a DATABASE_URL.
Network Configuration: Both services are on a custom Docker network.

What I’ve Tried:

Docker Network and DNS:


Verified the user-service container can ping the db container:

docker-compose exec user-service ping -c 4 192.168.144.2

This worked fine.

DNS resolution checked using:

docker-compose exec user-service nslookup db

This returned the correct IP address 192.168.144.2

PostgreSQL Configuration:


Modified pg_hba.conf to include the Docker network IP range

host all all 192.168.144.0/20 trust

Reloaded PostgreSQL configuration and confirmed it had no syntax errors.

Environment Variables:


Verified .env variables are correctly loaded in the user-service container:

DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:8911023@db:5432/creator_trends_user_service_dev


Docker Network Configuration:


Checked Docker network configuration:

docker network inspect user-service_user-service-network


Docker Compose and Volumes:


Ensured the db container is up and running with:

docker-compose logs db

Configuration Files:
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  user-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - user-service-network

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - user-service-network

networks:
  user-service-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:

.sequelizerc:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
};

Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Build Stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

# Install PostgreSQL client
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-client nano

# Copy the necessary files
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of your app's source code
COPY . .

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Production Stage
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install PostgreSQL client for runtime
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-client nano

# Copy files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/config/config.js ./config/config.js
COPY --from=builder /app/migrations ./migrations
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./

# Ensure production dependencies are installed
RUN npm install --production

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 3001

# Start the app
CMD ["node", "dist/server.js"]

.env:
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3001
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:8911023@db:5432/creator_trends_user_service_dev
DB_HOST=db
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=8911023
DB_NAME=creator_trends_user_service_dev
TEST_DB_NAME=creator_trends_user_service_test
PROD_DB_NAME=creator_trends_user_service_prod
DB_PORT=5432

config/config.js:
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false,
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TEST_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

db.ts:
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { config } from "dotenv";

config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

const databaseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

// Check if DATABASE_URL is set
if (!databaseUrl) {
  throw new Error("DATABASE_URL environment variable not set.");
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(databaseUrl, {
  dialect: "postgres",
  logging: process.env.SEQUELIZE_LOGGING === "true" ? console.log : false,
});

export default sequelize;

package.json:
{
  "name": "user-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && npm run copy-docs",
    "migrate": "sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "copy-docs": "cross-env node copy-docs.js",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "seed": "sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
    "test": "jest",
    "deploy": "./deploy.sh"

Additional Information:

I’ve checked for any firewall issues but found none.
Confirmed that the db service is accessible via other PostgreSQL clients.

Question:
Does anyone have insights into why the user-service might not be connecting to the db service despite having correct environment variables and network settings? Is there something I’m overlooking in the Docker or PostgreSQL configuration?
Thank you for your help!
